# Get files between date range in windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to get files between a date range in windows power shell but it's getting all the files instead of just the ones in range.

Here's my commands:

```
[datetime]$start = '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
[datetime]$end = '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\PC- 1\Downloads" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $start -or $_.LastWriteTime -lt $end }
```

Comment: Don't you want "-and" instead of "or"?

Comment: @Tung oops. you got that right. if you make that an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use the `-and` operator instead of `-or` to express "start < LastWriteTime < end"

```
[datetime]$start = '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
[datetime]$end = '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\PC- 1\Downloads" |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $start -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $end }
```

Comment: Note: to find files in subfolders, use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`.